# How to load an image inside a div specified in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Transparent image]

I need to add the below attached transparent image in each dynamic generated div mentioned in the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ramapriya/xeYnv/5/

```
for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    var $col = $("<div />", {
        class: "col",
        style: "background: " + get_random_color() + ";",
        id : ii + "-" + i
    });
    $row.append($col);
}
```

Comment: Where is the image in your code? Have you even tried it?

Comment: why not setting a class to the div, and specify the background image by CSS instead of doing it the hard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the background shorthand to set color and background image.

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    var $col = $("<div />", {
        class: "col",
        style: "background: " + get_random_color() + " url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBZ7q.png');",
        id : ii + "-" + i
    });
    $row.append($col);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xeYnv/7/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way at this line:

change this line:

```
style: "background: " + get_random_color() + ";",
```

with this:

```
style: "background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBZ7q.png') 0 0 no-repeat;",
```

where `https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBZ7q.png` is the path of the image.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xeYnv/6/)

#### Edit:

You can put with random colors this way:

```
style: "background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBZ7q.png') 0 0 no-repeat" + 
                    get_random_color() + ";",
```

[**Updated Fiddle with random colors and background image**](http://jsfiddle.net/xeYnv/8/)

Comment: I shouldnt remove the get_random_color() function.Instead of that i just need to add a glossy effect image to the dynamically generated background color